# Situations in which to use Singletons and OnePerThread patterns in web projects

Tags: design-patterns

I dont quite get when I should use a Singleton or OnePerThread pattern when building a web application.

Could anyone tell us some situations of when we should know to implement these patterns?

*Familiar with ASP.NET MVC.*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Generally, this is not the way to approach a problem: "What patterns should I use". Patters should come naturally.

For a web-app:

- one-per-thread is usually request data, because each request is handled by a separate thread - everything that needs to be specific for a given request is here. Example: A database connection. Each request is (generally) associated with one db connection. It cannot be shared among multiple requests.
- singleton - this is everything that is *stateless*, or more properly stated - there is only *one state* and it does not depend on the thread currently using the object. Example: a service that processed payments. It does not store any state - it just calls the payment provider given some payment parameters.

Comment: not ASP.NET ones :) But I'll try to think of some general one.

Comment: A singleton does not mean that everything is stateless, it means that you have an object of which you only want one around.

An example of using a singleton that I encountered recently is a TCP connection to a remote vendor. They had implemented their own data transfer protocol so I had to write a client for that, which needed to be able to access their systems over a single socket per web server.

Comment: @Joon that is an odd use-case. Anyway, I added a clarification about the state.